# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error despite .htaccess file set up to send the header

Tags: .htaccess

Browser's console gives me these two errors:

```
1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

2) new.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://static.example.com/img/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I think my .htaccess file is configured correctly though and placed inside the `img folder`

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com"
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)` You're sending that status somewhere, that seems independent from what you put in the img folder. Perhaps on a directory level further up

Comment: "The response had HTTP status code 403" is the error you should be solving. It doesn't have anything to do with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin rule.

Comment: And how can I solve that 403 error? can it be related to the redirect from non-www to www?